# Javascript Stationary footer covers focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a webpage I am working on where the page has a stationary footer at the bottom of the page.

https://littlemouseproductions.blob.core.windows.net/example/Footer%20Example.PNG

When the user tabs through the fields and sets the focus on an element that is below the stationary footer, the page does not scroll up to show the focused elements. Is there a way to use javascript to automatically scroll to ensure the focused element is always appearing above the footer?

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the Element.scrollIntoView() function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

```
    function setFocusToElement () {
      var element = document.getElementById("yourelement");
      element.focus();
      element.scrollIntoView();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your input fields are `<input>`s, you can do it like this with JavaScript:

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("input"), function(element) {
    element.addEventListener("focus", function(event) {
        window.location.href = location.pathname + "#" + event.target.id;
    })
})
```

This should do three things:

1. Iterate over each `<input>` element
2. Add an `onfocus` event listener to each `<input>` element
3. Set the window location to the filename, plus the hashtag selector for whichever element was just focused on.

Hopefully this helps you!

Here's a jQuery way of doing the same thing:

```
$("input").on("focus", function() {
    window.location.href = location.pathname + "#" + $(this).id;
})
```

Slightly simpler, but it does the same thing.